# CPU usage 350% while running DSE 4.x

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise

VM configuration is - CentOS 6.2, 64-bit, 8 GB RAM Quad Core CPU.

There is aboug 1 GB of data and possibly 20 tables in the C* setup I have. When I try to start DSE after rebooting the VM, it takes a long time to start. So I ran top command and found that the CPU usage was shooting to 350%[image]

Please see the screenshot attached.

Requesting pointers from experts here how can the CPU usage shoot up more than 100% or does the number indicate something else?

Comment: Is it replaying commit logs? Check the Cassandra logs. Normally on restart it will reply commit logs which will use lots of CPU for a while.

Comment: Thanks Richard. I will check that. But is it mathematically possible to use 350% of CPU? What does it mean in terms of system stability and has anyone has seen this before?

Comment: It's summed for each core. 350% means it's using 3.5 cores fully so it is common to see this on multicore systems. Cassandra makes good use of lots of cores so it's perfectly normal.

Comment: Thanks Richard. I also read that Linux calculates CPU usage differently. Another factor might be Solr and Hive queries impact CPU usage as per DataStax white paper I read. So I am closing the issue for now. I am also accepting Richard's answer as most logical at this point.